# Is this question valid? If $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ are complements, and the supplement of $\angle B$ is $78^\circ$, then find $\angle A$.

Tags: geometry, angle

> Question: Angle A and B are complementary. If the supplement of angle B is 78°. What is the measure of angle A?

I am confused since

- A + B = 90
- B + 78 = 180
- B = 102
- A + 102 = 90
- A = -12

I think the question should be the supplement of angle B is 102°.

> Is the question right or wrong?

Comment: Maybe they meant A and B are _supplementary_ and the _complement_ of B is 78°.  This gives positive non-reflex solution for A.

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed we have that

- $A+B=90°$
- $B+78=180° \implies B=102°$

then $A=-12°=348°$.

---

**Edit**

In the context of oriented angles, the result could be correct since it is fine to have negative values too for angles.

Otherwise there could be an error or a typo in the formulation of the problem.

Comment: So basically the question is wrong?

Comment: @WillieTaylor Not necessarly. In the context of oriented angles it is fine to have negative values too. What is the context?

Comment: Our teacher didn't discussed that, this is only 7th grade

Comment: @WillieTaylor: In that case, I think the question must be wrong.